# Show that the number of maximum fresh lines thus introduced is $\displaystyle\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $n$ straight lines in a plane in which no two are parallel and no three pass through the same point. Their points of intersection are joined. Show that the number of maximum fresh lines thus introduced is $\displaystyle\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}$.

Though I tried this questions many times but I'm kinda stuck

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: consider the case $n=4$ first.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492784/lines-drawn-from-the-intersection-of-the-given-lines

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lines drawn from the intersection of the given lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492784/lines-drawn-from-the-intersection-of-the-given-lines)

Comment: Try it yourself, show your efforts, maybe you'll get the answer in doing so. I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each pair of lines, there is an intersection point, so there are $\binom{n}{2}$ intersection ponts in total. Looking at one such point, it is the intersection of $2$ lines, and all other points that can be used to form a fresh line are intersection points of the remaining $n-2$ lines, so there are $\binom{n-2}{2}$ possible "partner points".

To calculate the maximum number of freh lines, we have to multiply both numbers, but we then have double counted each line, so we have to divide the result by $2$ to receive
$$
\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}
$$